# How can I run Spring and spring-boot application on same embedded activemq broker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have my legacy Spring application that is starting an embedded broker.

I am creating a microservice with spring boot and now I want to send message to my spring application on the same broker that can listen and proceed further.

I have tried the different solution but not able to send to my legacy application but if try in my spring boot application it is working fine.

following is connection factory configuration in legacy application:-

```
@Bean
    @DependsOn("SABrokerService")
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        log.debug("Creating Connection Factory which is dependent on Broker Service");
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        jmsConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("vm://SABroker");
        return jmsConnectionFactory;
    }
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: So to clarify your question , u want to send a message from your spring boot application to an embedded broker which is running inside a legacy spring application?

Comment: Yes @IndraneelBende

Comment: When the legacy spring application starts up do U know which port the broker starts on?

Comment: And U will not use this scenario in production .

Comment: it starts using broker service with broker URL :- vm://<application-name> at the time of legacy application starts

Comment: I debug the code but there was no TCP port was showing in broker service

Comment: What port does the embedded broker start on? Try connecting from ur spring boot application to the embedded broker on that port?

Comment: Can u post the logs when the legacy spring application starts up

Comment: they are not showing any port in logs even in debug mode,
@Bean
 @DependsOn("SABrokerService")
 public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
  log.debug("Creating Connection Factory which is dependent on Broker Service");
  ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
  jmsConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("vm://SABroker");
  return jmsConnectionFactory;
 }

Comment: Please edit and post this in ur question .

Comment: updated the post

Comment: In the above code where ur setting the url , mention a port

Comment: it will run inside JVM, there is not port

Comment: Mention a port in ur above code and see if u can connect to it . I know it runs inside jvm.

Comment: @IndraneelBende, tried the same what you have suggested but still queue is not listening in legacy application

Comment: Can u post a minimal verifiable sample on github of the legacy spring application  and post the link . I will take a look.